# Send data to a shiny R program

Tags: r, shiny, send

First of all I'm new to shiny.
I'd like to send a matrix of records to a shiny application so I can populate a control and generate a graph.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to have your ui code and server code in two seperate files but to write a function which contains your ui and server code.

Try this:

```
shinyapp <- function(mat) {
    app <- list(
        ui = bootstrapPage(
             here comes your ui.R),
        server = function(input, output) {
             here comes your server.R
             the argument mat can be used now in server
        }
    )
    runApp(app)
}
```

This worked for me.